# Is a finite normal subgroup of a reductive algebraic group central?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In a proof I am reading, the author considers the situation where $G$ is a reductive algebraic group (variety) over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$ is a closed, normal subgroup of $G$ which is also finite. The author concludes that *"because $G$ is reductive"*, $N$ must be contained in the center of $G$. I can't seem to make that same deduction, though. Is this some well-known result? Can you give a proof?

Btw, if $G$ is connected then this does not seem to have anything to do with reductivity at all. Let $u\in N$, then $G.u\subseteq N$ is finite. Since $0=\dim(G.u)=\dim(G)-\dim(G_u)$, the stabilizer of $u$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ which has maximal dimension, therefore $G=G_u$. However, the author explicitly states that the reductivity of $G$ is the reason for his deduction, and I am curious what that would be.

Comment: Can you state what definition of reductive you are using? In Milne's [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/RG.pdf) he has connectedness as part of the definition for a reductive group.

Comment: I will call $G$ reductive if its unipotent radical is trivial. Equivalently, you can use the definition that every finite-dimensional $G$-module is semisimple, i.e. a direct sum of irreducible $G$-modules.

Comment: If connectedness is missing from the definition of reductive (and this appears to be the case in the cited definition) then the result is false of course; you can take a finite group.

Comment: Note that the definition of reductive in terms of the modules being semisimple only works over $\mathbb{C}$ and not in positive characteristic. (By works, I mean is equivalent to the other one).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Can you give an example when we assume $G$ to be infinite, but not connected?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain: You can take a direct product of a finite group and an infinite connected group, but I'm not sure this is what you wanted. I think a reductive group cannot have infinitely many connected components. But your question does not talk about finite; the point is whether $G$ has to be a _single_ connected component. I've seen the adjectives "connected" and "reductive" been used together sufficiently often to be convinced that the latter does not (usually) by definition imply the former.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I think you misunderstood. I ment: Can you give an example of an infinite algebraic group $G$ which is not connected and such that a finite, normal subgroup $N\subseteq G$ exists which is not central? Because yes, I understand that a finite group $G$ is a counterexample, but I would like to know if there is an infinite counterexample.

Comment: I don't see why one could not blow up any finite counterexample to an infinite one by taking a direct product with an infinite group (for the finite subgroup take the direct product with just the identity element to keep it finite). As far as I can see failure to be normal survives this blowing up operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recall writing about this a while ago. This holds for connected algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $k$, not necessarily reductive: Let $H$ be the normal subgroup. Let $y\in H$ and let $G\to G$ be given by $x\mapsto xyx^{-1}$. Since $H$ is normal, this sends $G$ into $H$. The image of a connected group is connected, so the image is a single point. In particular, taking $x = 1_G$, we see that the image of $G$ is actually $y$. Hence $y$ commutes with every element of $G$.

If you take the definition of $G$ being reductive as just trivial unipotent radical, this is surely false. For instance, $N = G$, and $G$ a nonabelian finite group that is an algebraic group.

Comment: So I suppose this only works when we restrict ourselves to considering the algebraic group as a variety, as once we see them as schemes, we get finite closed normal non-central subgroups (at least in positive characteristic).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, any finite normal subgroup H of a connected algebraic group G is central. (Consider the action GxH->H by conjugation.  The orbits are connected.)

Comment: This is mentioned in the question.